# Swizzling +[NSObject initialize] method to log each class instantiation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swizzling

Basically, I want to print each time a class object is instantiated. The following code shows the intent.

```
@interface NSObject (ILogger)
+ (void)initialize;
@end

@implementation NSObject (ILogger)
+ (void)initialize
{
    NSLog(@"Initializing %s", class_getName([self class]));
}
@end
```

This does not work because `NSObject` already has a `+initialize` method so this approach results in undefined behavior. The compiler also warns about the issue: `warning: category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class`

One idea would be to somehow swizzle `+[NSObject initialize]` and do the logging. How do I do that safely?

**EDIT:**

Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology but the goal is to know if a class is used at all in the app. If many objects of a class are created, there is no need to log every time, once is sufficient.

Comment: "but the goal is to know if a class is used at all in the app." This is definitely impossible in the general case. Objective-C allows (and uses commonly) quite a wide variety of shenanigans for creating objects. Many things that look like NSObjects never actually call -init (or +alloc). As the most famous example, consider toll-free bridged types. They're not ObjC objects at all, even though they look like them. I would consider The Dreams Wind's answer closest, but it's not going to be anywhere close to complete, so it depends on what you really want to do with this information.

Comment: In addition to @RobNapier, `inititlize` idea could be easily broken if some classes have their own implementation of this method which don't call `super` implementation. Instead, i would recommend to get use of instruments (to watch all objects allocated over period of time and check whether they are of the type you are interested in) or xcode memory graph. Debugging tools give much more in-depth analysis than runtime manipulation may ever offer.

Comment: I agree this may not be possible in general case without an elaborate heuristic. It might take a while to get it to work 'to be good enough' and that is fine for my use case. Thanks both for your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## After Edit Answer

You are correct about use of `+[NSObject initialize]` method for tracking the first use of a class. I don't know anything more appropriate for that. The swizzling would look like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (InitializeLog)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(initialize));
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(tdw_initializeLog));

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);

    });
}

+ (void)tdw_initializeLog {
    const char *className = class_getName(self);
    printf("Initializing %s\n", className);
    [self tdw_initializeLog];
}

@end
```

There are a few things to be advised about:

1. `initialize` doesn't fallback to the `NSObject` implementation (which is swizzled above) if derived classes have this method implemented AND don't have `[super initialize];` called. Thus for any custom class inherited from Cocoa classes either don't implement this method OR call `[super initialize];` somewhere in your implementation:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    [super initialize];
    ...
}
```

2. Cocoa classes are rarely as straightforward as they look like. Quite a lot of interfaces and classes are hidden under the same name and sometimes the logs will be somewhat misleading (e.g. in place of `NSNumber` you will get `NSValue` class reported). Thus, take any logging out of Foundation classes with a grain of salt and always double-check where it comes from (also be ready that those classes won't be reported at all).
3. First use of `NSLog` also triggers some classes to initialise themselves and it make them to call `+[NSObject initialize]`. In order to avoid an infinite loop or bad_access errors I decided to use `printf` to log the fact of initialisation in my implementation.

---

## Original Answer

The [`+ (void)initialize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418639-initialize?language=objc) method has very little to do with objects instantiation, since it gets called for each Objective-C **class** shortly before it's first time used in your client code. It might be called multiple times if subclasses of a given class don't have this method implemented and never gets called afterward. Thus it's just a bad choice if you want to track **objects** instantiation.

However there are still a few options you may want to employ to track occasions of objects instantiation.

### Swizzling `-[NSObject init]`

First, I would consider `init` method of `NSObject`:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (InitLog)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(init));
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(initLog_tdw));

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);

    });
}

- (instancetype)initLog_tdw {
    self = [self initLog_tdw];
    if (self) {
        const char *className = class_getName([self class]);
        NSLog(@"Instantiating %s", className);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

It will work fine as long as instances falls back to the `-[NSObject init]` method. Unfortunately quite a lot of Cocoa classes don't do that. Consider the following scenario:

```
NSObject *obj = [NSObject new]; // NSLog prints "Instantiating NSObject"
NSString *hiddenStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Test"]; // NSLog is silent
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; // NSLog is silent
```

`-[NSURL initWithString:]` and `-[NSMutableString initWithString:]` somehow avoids `NSObject`'s default constructor being called. It will still work for any custom classes which don't have any fancy initialisation:

```
@implementation TDWObject

- (instancetype)initWithNum:(int)num {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _myNum = num;
    }
    return self;
}

@end

TDWObject *customObj = [TDWObject new]; // NSLog prints "Instantiating TDWObject"
TDWObject *customObjWithNum = [[TDWObject alloc] initWithNum:2]; // NSLog prints "Instantiating TDWObject"
```

### Swizzling `+[NSObject alloc]`

Alternatively you can swizzle the `alloc` method:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (AllocLog)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(alloc));
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(tdw_allocLog));

        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);

    });
}

+ (instancetype)tdw_allocLog {
    id allocatedObject = [self tdw_allocLog];
    if (allocatedObject) {
        const char *className = class_getName([allocatedObject class]);
        NSLog(@"Allocating %s", className);
    }
    return allocatedObject;
}

@end
```

It will intercept almost all Cocoa classes instantiation (the exception must be some of the fabric methods, where class-specific optimisation takes place, e.g. `+[NSNumber numberWith..]` family of methods), but there are other problems to be aware of. The allocated instances returned from `alloc` method are not always that straightforward. E.g. for `NSMutableString` example above `NSLog` will print `NSPlaceholderMutableString`:

```
TDWObject *customObj = [TDWObject new]; // NSLog prints "Allocating TDWObject"
TDWObject *customObjWithNum = [[TDWObject alloc] initWithNum:2]; // NSLog prints "Allocating TDWObject"
NSObject *obj = [NSObject new]; // NSLog prints "Allocating NSObject"
NSString *hiddenStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Test"]; // NSLog prints "Allocating NSPlaceholderMutableString"
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; // NSLog prints "Allocating NSURL"
```

That's is because Foundation framework [uses Class Cluster design pattern heavily](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) and instances returned by `alloc` are often some kind of abstract factories, which are later leveraged by Cocoa classes to make a concrete instance of the class requested.

---

Both approaches have their own downsides, but I struggle to come up with anything more concise and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer with explanation! Won't this approach call NSLog multiple times on the same class if multiple instances are created? e.g., while creating an array of objects of the same type. With `+initialize` the log will print only once for each class.

Comment: @A.K. i edited my answer to provide info on what you were looking for.

Comment: Worked nicely! Thanks a lot! It'll be nice to extend this answer for swift as well.

Comment: @A.K. for Swift it will not be a universal solution as you can define new classes without subclassing any of cocoa classes (`NSObject` in this case) in Swift

Comment: Ah too bad, for my use case ;) nvm then

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to do this with breakpoint if only need logging, I've not tested it with `initialize`, but does works on my case with `dealloc`, note that it might print a lot more than you actually needed and slow down performance:

- In Xcode, go to the Breakpoint navigator (Cmd+8)
- At the bottom-left on the screen, tap '+', then select "Symbolic Breakpoint..." from the menu
- Fill the form:

  - Symbol: `-[NSObject initialize]`
  - Action: Select "Log Message"
  - Enter: `--- init @(id)[$arg1 description]@ @(id)[$arg1 title]@`
  - Select "Log message to console"
  - Check "Automatically continue after evaluating actions" so Xcode does not stop at the breakpoint

Comment: This might work with XCode for debugging something, but this approach is not scalable for keeping track of all the initialized objects in an app.

Comment: That's right since it slow down performance a lot, but it's simple and safe. If you want otherwise the only way is swizzling using `method_exchangeImplementations`

Comment: Just to clarify: `+initialize` has nothing to do with creating instances of objects. Here you would need `+alloc`. `+initialize` is called the very first time a class is used. Also other than for educational reasons, keeping track of all your objects this way seems impractical. And even for that there are profiling tools which are better suited.

Comment: >> +initialize is called the very first time a class is used.                                                  
yes that is why +initialize is helpful because it will only print the log when an object is created for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible solution I found was swizzling `-[NSObject init]` this was tested only in a small test project

I have an article about swizzling that maybe you will find interesting [medium article](https://medium.com/edreams-odigeo-tech/hard-crashes-swizzling-method-to-the-rescue-adb257453767)

```
extension NSObject {

    static let swizzleInit: Void = {
        DispatchQueue.once(token: "NSObject.initialize.swizzle") {
            let originalSelector = Selector("init")
            let swizzledSelector = #selector(swizzledInitialize)
            guard let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSObject.self, originalSelector),
                  let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSObject.self, swizzledSelector)
            else {
                debugPrint("Error while swizzling")
                return
            }
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }()

    @objc
    private func swizzledInitialize() -> Self? {
        debugPrint("\(Self.self) has been initialized")
        return swizzledInitialize()
    }
}
```

`DispatchQueue.once` implementation in [DispatchQueue.once gist](https://medium.com/edreams-odigeo-tech/hard-crashes-swizzling-method-to-the-rescue-adb257453767)

Then in **AppDelegate** ...

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        NSObject.swizzleInit
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

[image]